# Fill NA's using a panel regression of specific AR(1) form

Tags: r, time-series, na, imputation

I need to fill NA's using a panel regression of this specific form (AR(1):

[image: Formula]

β should be estimated recursively over the sample period.
The formula can also be found in Genre et al. (2013), "Combining expert forecasts: Can anything beat the simple Average?" , p.112f.

This is my Data:

```
         Dez 1999 Mrz 2000 Jun 2000 Sep 2000 Dez 2000 Mrz 2001 Jun 2001 Sep 2001
 [1,]      1.2      1.4      1.5      1.8      1.9      1.9      2.0      1.9
 [2,]      1.2      1.2       NA      1.6       NA      2.0       NA      2.5
 [3,]      1.3      1.7       NA      1.7      1.8      1.5      1.8      1.5
 [4,]      1.1      1.4      1.4      1.5      1.6      1.6      1.7      1.9
 [5,]      1.6      1.9      1.5      1.4      1.3      0.9       NA      1.7
 [6,]      0.9      1.8      1.6       NA       NA      1.8      1.8      1.8
 [7,]      1.4      1.8       NA      1.6      1.8      1.7       NA      1.8
 [8,]      1.4      1.3      1.7      1.5      1.6      1.5      1.9      1.6
 [9,]      1.8      2.0      1.9      1.9      1.8      1.8      2.2      2.0
[10,]      1.3      1.7      1.6      1.6      1.6      1.8      2.1      1.7
[11,]      1.0       NA      1.7      1.7       NA       NA       NA      1.7
```

I found the imputeTS package in R , but I dont know if it can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**imputeTS** might help you here, but might not be exactly what you are looking for. The `na_kalman` function provides imputation by Kalman Smoothing on the state space representation of an ARIMA model. You can build a `AR(1)` - autoregressive model of order 1, which means a `ARIMA(1,0,0)` model and give it to the `na_kalman` function.

```
library(imputeTS)

# You need to transpose rows/columns to use imputeTS
yourdata <- t(initialdata)

# Create AR(1) model
usermodel <- arima(yourdata, order = c(1, 0, 0))$model

# Use model for imputation
na_kalman(yourdata, model = usermodel)
```

So this would use a AR(1) model for each of your individuals.

[image]

Thus, this model would employ inter-time correlations for each individual separately. But would not use possible information from inter-individual correlations for imputation. So you see, the package specializes on univariate time series imputation.
Wasn't able to find you paper (maybe also post a doi) to take a closer look, but right now I wouldn't have a suggestion for a package, which has a easy to use imputation function with your desired model.

Comment: thanks Steffen, i was thinking about using the kalman filter like you in the imputeTS package! The DOI from the paper is "doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2012.06.004"